# Skip VS Code terminal shell arguments for launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In my workspace settings I have

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [
    "-c",
    "yarn custom_shell"
  ],
}
```

which launches a custom shell that prompts for user input on startup.

When I create a `launch.json` config that launches using the integrated terminal my `yarn custom_shell` command will run and wait for input, causing the launch command supplied by VS Code to fail to run. This same issue occurs for extensions that launch a program in my integrated terminal.

Is there a way to launch the integrated terminal with `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` *only* when it is an interactive user shell, not a shell started by an extension or `launch.json` config?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is to keep the integrated shell to behave as expected and to use [shell-launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) extension for hacking different shells in vscode (it might also save you the need to wait for user input in your custom shell):

```
  "shellLauncher.shells.linux": [
      {
          "shell": "bash",
          "args": ["-c yarn custom_shell"],
          "label": "my_custom_yarn_shell"
      }
  ]
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for this case. I'll wait to see if there is a native solution posted before accepting your answer.